# value to be passed to the fileName of appengine/file.Delete () is?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to know is fileName to pass when you delete a file of gcs from gae/go.

Although passed "/gs/{bucketname}/{filename}", error message "RPC error UNKNOWN_ERROR:" is returned

```
package main

import (
    "appengine"
    "appengine/file"

    "net/http"
)

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    file.Delete(c, "/gs/{bucketname}/{filename}")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Go but to work with Cloud Storage you need the Google Cloud Storage Go Client Library as indicated here [1].

Take a look at this sample code [2], more specifically to the deleteFiles() fuction. You can see that the function to the delete files is DeleteObject [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/storage#google_cloud_storage

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

[3] http://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/storage#DeleteObject

Comment: Thank you. It is a pity that appengine/file package does not work , but you may want to consider using the cloud/storage package.